# How do I create a PagedList of an object for tests?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I have been working with the arch libraries from Google, but one thing that has made testing difficult is working with `PagedList`.

For this example, I am using the repository pattern and returning details from either an API or network.

So within the ViewModel I make a call to this interface method:

```
override fun getFoos(): Observable<PagedList<Foo>>
```

The Repository will then use `RxPagedListBuilder` to create the `Observable` that is of type PagedList:

```
 override fun getFoos(): Observable<PagedList<Foo>> =
            RxPagedListBuilder(database.fooDao().selectAll(), PAGED_LIST_CONFIG).buildObservable()
```

I want to be able for tests to setup the return from these methods that return a `PagedList<Foo>`.  Something similar to

```
when(repository.getFoos()).thenReturn(Observable.just(TEST_PAGED_LIST_OF_FOOS)
```

Two questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. How do I create a `PagedList<Foo>`?

My goal is to verify in a more end-to-end fashion (such as ensuring that the correct list of Foos is displayed on the screen).  The fragment/activity/view is the one observing the `PagedList<Foo>` from a ViewModel.

Comment: What I find is missing from your question is: what verification do you want to make in the tests?

Comment: @arekolek thank you for the feedback...I updated the question with what I'm trying to verify

Comment: Any update on which strategy you implemented @isuPatches? I'm working on writing the same test with Kotlin, JUnit 5, and MockK. I'm happy to share my solution here once I get the proof of concept working.

Answer (score 17):

## Paging 3

The Paging 3 library offers a builder method [`PagingData.from(someList)`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/paging#version_300_2).

## Paging 2

Convert List Into PagedList With a Mock `DataSource.Factory`.

[@saied89](https://github.com/saied89) shared this [solution](https://github.com/saied89/DVDPrism/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/saied/dvdprism/app/PagedListMock.kt) in this [googlesamples/android-architecture-components](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/287) issue. I've implemented the mocked PagedList in the [Coinverse Open App](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse) in order to local unit test a ViewModel using Kotlin, JUnit 5, MockK, and AssertJ libraries.

To observe the LiveData from the PagedList I've used [Jose Alcérreca's](https://twitter.com/ppvi)  [implementation](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unit-testing-livedata-and-other-common-observability-problems-bb477262eb04) of `getOrAwaitValue` from the [LiveDataSample sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/LiveDataSample) under Google's Android Architecture Components samples.

The `asPagedList` extension function is implemented in the sample test *ContentViewModelTest.kt* below.

*PagedListTestUtil.kt*

```
    import android.database.Cursor
    import androidx.paging.DataSource
    import androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder
    import androidx.paging.PagedList
    import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
    import androidx.room.RoomSQLiteQuery
    import androidx.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource
    import io.mockk.every
    import io.mockk.mockk

    fun <T> List<T>.asPagedList() = LivePagedListBuilder<Int, T>(createMockDataSourceFactory(this),
        Config(enablePlaceholders = false,
                prefetchDistance = 24,
                pageSize = if (size == 0) 1 else size))
        .build().getOrAwaitValue()

    private fun <T> createMockDataSourceFactory(itemList: List<T>): DataSource.Factory<Int, T> =
        object : DataSource.Factory<Int, T>() {
            override fun create(): DataSource<Int, T> = MockLimitDataSource(itemList)
        }

    private val mockQuery = mockk<RoomSQLiteQuery> {
        every { sql } returns ""
    }

    private val mockDb = mockk<RoomDatabase> {
        every { invalidationTracker } returns mockk(relaxUnitFun = true)
    }

    class MockLimitDataSource<T>(private val itemList: List<T>) : LimitOffsetDataSource<T>(mockDb, mockQuery, false, null) {
        override fun convertRows(cursor: Cursor?): MutableList<T> = itemList.toMutableList()
        override fun countItems(): Int = itemList.count()
        override fun isInvalid(): Boolean = false
        override fun loadRange(params: LoadRangeParams, callback: LoadRangeCallback<T>) { /* Not implemented */ }

        override fun loadRange(startPosition: Int, loadCount: Int) =
            itemList.subList(startPosition, startPosition + loadCount).toMutableList()

        override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams, callback: LoadInitialCallback<T>) {
            callback.onResult(itemList, 0)
        }
    }
```

*LiveDataTestUtil.kt*

```
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

    /**
     * Gets the value of a [LiveData] or waits for it to have one, with a timeout.
     *
     * Use this extension from host-side (JVM) tests. It's recommended to use it alongside
     * `InstantTaskExecutorRule` or a similar mechanism to execute tasks synchronously.
     */
    fun <T> LiveData<T>.getOrAwaitValue(
        time: Long = 2,
        timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        afterObserve: () -> Unit = {}
    ): T {
        var data: T? = null
        val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        val observer = object : Observer<T> {
            override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
                data = o
                latch.countDown()
                this@getOrAwaitValue.removeObserver(this)
            }
        }
        this.observeForever(observer)
        afterObserve.invoke()
        // Don't wait indefinitely if the LiveData is not set.
        if (!latch.await(time, timeUnit)) {
            this.removeObserver(observer)
            throw TimeoutException("LiveData value was never set.")
        }
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return data as T
    }
```

*ContentViewModelTest.kt*

```
    ...
    import androidx.paging.PagedList
    import com.google.firebase.Timestamp
    import io.mockk.*
    import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith

    @ExtendWith(InstantExecutorExtension::class)
    class ContentViewModelTest {
        val timestamp = getTimeframe(DAY)

        @BeforeAll
        fun beforeAll() {
            mockkObject(ContentRepository)
        }

        @BeforeEach
        fun beforeEach() {
            clearAllMocks()
        }

        @AfterAll
        fun afterAll() {
            unmockkAll()
        }

        @Test
        fun `Feed Load`() {
            val content = Content("85", 0.0, Enums.ContentType.NONE, Timestamp.now(), "",
                "", "", "", "", "", "", MAIN,
                0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            every {
                getMainFeedList(any(), any())
            } returns liveData { 
               emit(Lce.Content(
                   ContentResult.PagedListResult(
                        pagedList = liveData {emit(listOf(content).asPagedList())}, 
                        errorMessage = ""))
            }
            val contentViewModel = ContentViewModel(ContentRepository)
            contentViewModel.processEvent(ContentViewEvent.FeedLoad(MAIN, DAY, timestamp, false))
            assertThat(contentViewModel.feedViewState.getOrAwaitValue().contentList.getOrAwaitValue()[0])
                .isEqualTo(content)
            assertThat(contentViewModel.feedViewState.getOrAwaitValue().toolbar).isEqualTo(
                ToolbarState(
                        visibility = GONE,
                        titleRes = app_name,
                        isSupportActionBarEnabled = false))
            verify {
                getMainFeedList(any(), any())
            }
            confirmVerified(ContentRepository)
        }
    }
```

*InstantExecutorExtension.kt*

This is required for JUnit 5 when using LiveData in order to ensure the Observer is not on the main thread. Below is [Jeroen Mols'](https://twitter.com/molsjeroen) [implementation](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/01/17/livedatajunit5/).

```
    import androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor
    import androidx.arch.core.executor.TaskExecutor
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterEachCallback
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext

    class InstantExecutorExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {
        override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
            ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(object : TaskExecutor() {
                override fun executeOnDiskIO(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()
                override fun postToMainThread(runnable: Runnable) = runnable.run()
                override fun isMainThread(): Boolean = true
            })
        }

        override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext?) {
            ArchTaskExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
        }
    }
```

Comment: would it be similar for paging 3 lib?

Comment: Great question @Raghunandan! I have not tested the Paging 3 library yet. Please follow-up on the post with comments/edits if you implement and find changes.

Answer (score 12):

an easy way to achieve this, is to mock the PagedList. This fun will "convert" a list to a PagedList (in this case, we are not using the real PagedList rather just a mocked version, if you need other methods of PagedList to be implemented, add them in this fun)

```
 fun <T> mockPagedList(list: List<T>): PagedList<T> {
     val pagedList = Mockito.mock(PagedList::class.java) as PagedList<T>
     Mockito.`when`(pagedList.get(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt())).then { invocation ->
        val index = invocation.arguments.first() as Int
        list[index]
     }
     Mockito.`when`(pagedList.size).thenReturn(list.size)
     return pagedList
 }
```

Comment: Don't forget to add Mockito first: `testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.25.0"`

Comment: Can you cast a `List` to a `PagedList` @bsobat?

Comment: @bsobat, Is this supposed to return a `PagedList` with data populated or an empty `PagedList` to avoid the test from failing? If empty, it will not be useful for testing how the app handles `PagedList` data.

Comment: @Hurwitz no, you can't cast

Comment: @bsobat, check out the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57794102/2253682) above that uses MockK to implement the behavior of using a PagedList when writing local JUnit 5 tests.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot cast List to PagedList.
2. You cannot create PagedList directly, only through DataSource. One way is creating FakeDataSource returning the test data.

If it is an end-to-end test, you could just use in-memory db. Add your test data before calling it. Example: 
https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-architecture-components-testing-your-room-dao-classes-e06e1c9a1535

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I've [implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57794102/2253682) a mock PagedList using MockK for a local JUnit 5 test.