# Unit testing Paging jetpack library used with PagedList.BoundaryCallback<T>() with PagedList<T> and DataSource.Factory<Int, T>

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-jetpack, android-paging

**Issue:**

I am working with [`Paging`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) library provided by [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack) and I am not able to test the `PagedList<T>` and `DataSource.Factory<Int, T>` data used with `PagedList.BoundaryCallback<T>()` in my `ViewModel` 

My code for receiving `PagedList` data using `PagedList.BoundaryCallback<T>()` and `PagedList.Config.Builder()` ::

```
final var boundaryCallback = MyBoundaryCallback(
        webServiceApi, mainRepository, PAGE_SIZE, appExecutors)

private final val pagedListConfig = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPrefetchDistance(PREFETCH_DISTANCE)
        .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE)
        .build()

var pagedListData: LiveData<PagedList<MyData>> =
        LivePagedListBuilder(dbDAO.loadAllPagedData(), pagedListConfig)
                .setBoundaryCallback(boundaryCallback)
                .build()
```

And my class MyBoundaryCallback :

```
class MyBoundaryCallback (private val webServiceApi: ApiService,
                               private val mainRepository: MainRepository,
                               private val networkPageLimit: Int,
                               private val appExecutors: AppExecutors) : PagedList.BoundaryCallback<MyData>() {

override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
    webServiceApi.getData(0, networkPageLimit).enqueue(WebserviceCallback())
}

override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: MyData) {
    webServiceApi.getData((itemAtEnd.id!! + 1), networkPageLimit).enqueue(WebserviceCallback())
}

private fun handleResponse(response: Response<List<MyData>>) {
    appExecutors.diskIO().execute {
        mainRepository.insertResultIntoDb(response.body())
    }
}

inner class WebserviceCallback : Callback<List<MyData>> {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyData>>, t: Throwable) {

    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<MyData>>, response: Response<List<MyData>>) {
        handleResponse(response)
    }
}
}
```

Since the class `MyBoundaryCallback` is pushing the data as you can see the code in my `ViewModel` above, the `LiveData` object is fetching the data from my room Db since it gives out `DataSource.Factory<Int, T>`, find the code below :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM mydata")
fun loadAllPagedData(): DataSource.Factory<Int, MyData>
```

I am not sure how to mock the `PagedData` so if anyone has any idea how to approach this please share

For Simple List of data I am able to test it with something like the code below :

```
@Test
fun testBasicData() {
    val dbMyData = MutableLiveData<List<MyData>>()
    val observer = mock<Observer<List<MyData>>>()
    Mockito.`when`(deliveriesDAO.loadAllData()).thenReturn(dbDeliveriesData)
    val list = MyMockDataGenerator.createList(4)
    dbDeliveriesData.observeForever(observer)
    dbDeliveriesData.value = list
    Mockito.verify(observer).onChanged(list)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a PagedList of an object for tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435770/how-do-i-create-a-pagedlist-of-an-object-for-tests)